# Add command line argument to Makefile from CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, arguments

I am using CMake to create a makefile for my project. I would like my Makefile to have several if's like:

```
ifeq "$(ARM)" "1"
  # do something
endif
```

Is something like that possible from CMake?

Comment: It depends entirely on what your `# do something` actually is.  The short answer is no, you can't do something like that: you have to put all that code into the CMakeLists.txt file.  You can't write GNU make operations in a CMake file (for one thing, the entire point of using CMake is to abstract the build from any given tool: by using CMake you can generate build control files not just for make but also for other tools like ninja, Visual Studio, Xcode, etc.

Comment: I should point out, that regardless of what `# do something` is, you can definitely do it in CMake.  But, the syntax and implementation could be very different.